Divergence of light rays - parallel approximation
On this page:
https://www.handprint.com/ASTRO/ae1.html
the author gives this calculation to show light rays from very distant objects are essentially parallel:

In astronomical applications, light sources are so distant that the
concentric wavefronts become a series of equally spaced parallel
planes across the width of any practical telescope aperture. To
illustrate: across the aperture of a 1 meter (39.4") telescope, light
rays from a single point on the Moon, the closest astronomical object
at 384,403 kilometers, diverge from parallel by no more than
1/384403000 of a radian or 0.0000026 millimeter, which is 0.0047 or
1/200 a wavelength of "green" light. Since the fabrication limits of
the highest quality astronomical optics are around λ/20 wave, or 10
times larger than the wavefront divergence, optical calculations can
assume perfectly flat and parallel wavefronts from a distant light
source.

I don't follow the steps in this reasoning. Is he using a small angle approximation? I know it's very elementary, but could somebody explain it to me?


Is he using a small angle approximation?

Yes!
Consider this triangle:

The bottom side which I labeled "384403000 m" as the Earth-Moon distance, and "1 m" is the diameter of the aperture. The angle $\theta$ is the angular separation of two rays, in your words, the divergence of two light rays. By trig function:
$$\tan\theta = \frac{1}{384403000}.$$
Because the fraction is so small, when one expand the $\tan \theta$ function by Taylor series, all the quantities with high orders will be practically seen as 0, which gives $\tan \theta \approx \theta$, in your words, the small angle approximation. So now we reduce $\tan  \theta$ to only $\theta$.
Note $\theta$ is also extremely small, so we can approximate $\theta \approx 0$. Remember the unit of the angle is radian! Not degree!
That is the answer of your question, $\theta$ is just too small for astronomers to consider about it.

“Figure not to scale” :-)

There are some potential exceptions that prove the rule: Did this satellite streak past the Hubble Space Telescope so close that it was out of focus? If so, how close was it? and Has Hubble ever focused on something close enough that it had to move away from being focused at infinity? For things closer than say 18,000 km for a 2 meter aperture (and further for larger), the parallel ray approximation gives the wrong answer.

Don't forget (@andro) that θ has to be in radians for the small angle approximation (something I think is always worth stating explicitly when the context is a self-described beginner question)
